# How to Split a paragraph into sentences separated by period(.) except when the period is a part of an abbreviation?

Tags: regex, string, parsing

Consider this text paragraph

> Conservation groups call the 20-year ban a crucial protection for an American icon. The mining industry and some Republican members of Congress say it is detrimental to Arizona's economy and the nation's energy independence."Despite significant pressure from the mining industry, the president and Secretary Salazar did not back down," said Jane Danowitz, U.S. public lands director for the Pew Environment Group.

In the above, its easy to split sentences over period(.) but it will lead to incorrect results when it processes the period in U.S.A.  . Assume I have a list of abbreviations such as

```
String abbrev[] ={"u.s.a", "u.a.e", "u.k", "p.r.c","u.s.s.r", };
String regex= "\\.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sx);
int beginIndex=0;

// Check all occurance
int index=0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");

    String group=matcher.group();
    System.out.println("group: " + group);
    int dotIndex= group.indexOf(".");
    String sub= sx.substring(beginIndex, matcher.start()+dotIndex);
    beginIndex= matcher.start()+dotIndex;

    System.out.println(sub);
}
```

I could do a brute force match with all the abbreviations  around dotIndex. Is there a better approach ?

Comment: Can you just take advantage of the space following a regular sentence, or are there other boundary conditions?

Comment: @JoshG: I thought about that, but what about other cases, e.g. this very example with `e.g.` and a space. You'd need to verify (or negate) based on what's before it, like `(?<!\.[a-z])\.\s` (needs a period and a space where it's not preceded by a period and a letter.)

Comment: How are you planning to distinguish an abbreviation in the middle of a sentence versus one at the end of a sentence?  For example, "I live in the U.S."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess would be something like: `(?<!\.[a-zA-Z])\.(?![a-zA-Z]\.)` which would translate to:

```
(?<!\.[a-zA-Z])    # can't be preceded by a period followed by a single letter
\.
(?![a-zA-Z]\.)     # nor can it be followed by a letter and another preiod
```

Then you can perform the replace from there.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?2vltd)

*This would require a lot more effort if you needed to catch period within quotes though, which is **not** accounted for in the above pattern.*

Comment: what about the abbreviation vs.

Comment: @insipid: You could either alter the quantifier to accept `{1,2}` (on the basis that a sentence doesn't usually end in two-letter words), or capture the word before each instance and test it against an exceptions list (including abbreviations like `vs`) before proceeding to parse it.

Comment: @Brad: And what about in. (as in inches)?  That can be either one.  Adding it to a whitelist wouldn't be enough.

Comment: @CHao: parsing text is a full time position. You can almost always do something to 80%, it's making a 99/100% rule that proves difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This problem cannot be solved by relying on regular expressions.  To know whether a sentence ends at any given period is not simple.  Abbreviations may or may not be the end of a sentence.  Ellipses may be written as three periods (or, in some circumstances, four, depending on the prevailing style).  Sentences sometimes end after a closing quotation mark that comes after a period that marks the end of the sentence (again depending on prevailing style).

You can use heuristics to get the answer right most of the time.  But it's more of a statistical problem than a regex problem.